# How to select every field from foreign table using intermediate table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about pure SQL. I have a many to many relation with 3 tables: `users`, `tags` and `user_tag`. What I'm trying to do is select every field from the `tags` table, for as many entries where the user id matches the entries in `user_tag`.

The query I have right now looks like this
`SELECT * FROM tags JOIN users_tags ON (users_tags.user_id = 1);`

This retrieves the correct information (twice for some odd reason) but also  appends unnecessary data from the pivot table (because of the `SELECT *`, but I need to keep it that way).
How can I only get relevant data from the `tags` table only then? (edited)
 Thanks for your attention

Comment: What's pure sql?

Comment: The question is hard to understand... Example?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `JOIN` condition that connects the two tables.  You only have a filtering condition.  Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tags t JOIN
     users_tags ut
     ON t.tag_id = ut.tag_id
WHERE ut.user_id = 1;
```

You haven't explained what the columns are, so of course the column names might be different.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works or i'm assuming if there's some name you want from the `user` table you could use this or a variation of this:

```
SELECT user.name, tags.* 
FROM tags 
INNER JOIN users_tags ON tags.tag_id = users_tags.tag_id
INNER JOIN user ON users_tags.user_id = users.user_id
where users_tags = 1;
```